# ManyToMany error : Argument 1 passed to Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection::__construct() must be of the type array, object given

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I have a problem with type ManyToMany relations entities.

I learn symfony i make maybe something wrong.

I tried many ways (Without foreach ...) but i fall always on errors.

These entities were created whit the CLI.

Thanks for your replys and sorry for my bad english

**My entities :**

**Clients**

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use App\Repository\ClientsRepository;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=ClientsRepository::class)
 */
class Clients
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $nom;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $prenom;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $mail;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
     */
    private $created_at;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="boolean")
     */
    private $actif;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity=Services::class, mappedBy="clients")
     */
    private $services;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->services = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getNom(): ?string
    {
        return $this->nom;
    }

    public function setNom(string $nom): self
    {
        $this->nom = $nom;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getPrenom(): ?string
    {
        return $this->prenom;
    }

    public function setPrenom(?string $prenom): self
    {
        $this->prenom = $prenom;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getMail(): ?string
    {
        return $this->mail;
    }

    public function setMail(string $mail): self
    {
        $this->mail = $mail;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getCreatedAt(): ?\DateTimeInterface
    {
        return $this->created_at;
    }

    public function setCreatedAt(\DateTimeInterface $created_at): self
    {
        $this->created_at = $created_at;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getActif(): ?bool
    {
        return $this->actif;
    }

    public function setActif(bool $actif): self
    {
        $this->actif = $actif;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection|Services[]
     */
    public function getServices(): Collection
    {
        return $this->services;
    }

    public function addService(Services $service): self
    {
        if (!$this->services->contains($service)) {
            $this->services[] = $service;
            $service->setClients($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeService(Services $service): self
    {
        if ($this->services->contains($service)) {
            $this->services->removeElement($service);
            // set the owning side to null (unless already changed)
            if ($service->getClients() === $this) {
                $service->setClients(null);
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }
}
```

**Services**

```
    <?php

namespace App\Entity;

use App\Repository\ServicesRepository;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;


/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=ServicesRepository::class)
 */
class Services
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $nom;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="float")
     */
    private $prix;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity=Clients::class, inversedBy="services")
     */
    private $clients;
    
   
    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getNom(): ?string
    {
        return $this->nom;
    }

    public function setNom(string $nom): self
    {
        $this->nom = $nom;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getPrix(): ?float
    {
        return $this->prix;
    }

    public function setPrix(float $prix): self
    {
        $this->prix = $prix;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getClients(): ?Clients
    {
        return $this->clients;
    }

    public function setClients(?Clients $clients): self
    {
        $this->clients = $clients;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

**Controller**

```
    [...]
    $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    foreach($servicesClient as $srv){
                    
        $service = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Services::class)->find($srv);
                    
        $service->setClients($client);
        $client->addService($service);
                    
        $entityManager->persist($client);
        $entityManager->persist($service);
        $entityManager->flush();
                    
      }
      [...]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `Service::clients` property is marked with `@ManyToMany` annotation, which means it should be typed `@var Collection|Clients[]` but both getter and setter returns/set a nullable object `?Clients $clients`.

No way the `bin/console make:entity` did that.

You should use the same system as your `Clients::services` property, i.e using three methods `getClients()`, `addClients()` and `removeClients()` without `setClients()`. Besides, you need a constructor starting the `$clients` property: `$this->clients = new ArrayCollection();`.

Or maybe you want to use `@OneToMany` and `@ManyToOne` annotations.

Note that an entity classname should be singular.

Comment: I think your solution is good

but i think forget something

so i have retried with the CLI and 
it works

thanks for your help